# Is there any way to set the selected item in listview?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I use `ListView` with link like this:

```
<ul data-dividertheme="d" data-theme="c" data-role="listview" style="width:100%;margin: 0px" >
   <li><a href="javascript:LoadPrimaryContent('#divTopicsPrimary','#pageNewTopic')">新主题</a></li>
   <li data-role="divider"></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:GotoThreadList('invited')">我参与的主题</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:GotoThreadList('mine')">我的主题</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:GotoThreadList('replied')">我的回复</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is a strange behavior, when I click the first link once, the item appears selected, and could not click anymore. But the second and the third does not have that issue.

What I want to know is how to control the item that selected to follow the script I wrote.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this instead:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LoadPrimaryContent('#divTopicsPrimary','#pageNewTopic')">新建主题</a></li>
```

Comment: The first on don't selected,thank you.But I still want to know how to select the item I want.